# Webots E-Puck localization VERY incaccurate (python)

Tags: python, localization, gps, webots

I need to make a robot which follows a line, then heads off the line when close to the goal and then rejoins the line. but the localization program which has been provided has proven itself to be inaccurate.

```
"""Lab3 controller."""


#  from controller import Robot, Motor, DistanceSensor
from controller import Robot, DistanceSensor, Motor
import numpy as np
# create the Robot instance.
robot = Robot()

# define max speed
MAX_SPEED = 6.28

# get the time step of the current world.
TIMESTEP = 32 # ms
delta_t = TIMESTEP/1000.0 #s

runtime = 0
totalS = 0

# Robot pose
# Adjust the initial values to match the initial robot pose in your simulation
x = 0    # position in x [m]
y = 0.45    # position in y [m]
phi = -0  # orientation [rad]

# Robot velocity and acceleration
dx = 0.0   # speed in x [m/s]
dy = 0.0   # speed in y [m/s]
ddx = 0.0  # acceleration in x [m/s^2]
ddy = 0.0  # acceleration in y [m/s^2]

# Robot wheel speeds
wl = 0.0    # angular speed of the left wheel [rad/s]
wr = 0.0    # angular speed of the right wheel [rad/s]

# Robot linear and angular speeds
u = 0.0    # linear speed [m/s]
w = 0.0    # angular speed [rad/s]

# e-puck Physical parameters for the kinematics model (constants)
R = 0.0205    # radius of the wheels: 20.5mm [m]
D = 0.0565    # distance between the wheels: 52mm [m]
A = 0.05    # distance from the center of the wheels to the point of interest [m]

# initz line sensors
gs = []
gsNames = ['gs0', 'gs1', 'gs2']
for i in range(3):
    gs.append(robot.getDevice(gsNames[i]))
    gs[i].enable(TIMESTEP)


# encoders
encoder = []
encoderNames = ['left wheel sensor', 'right wheel sensor']
for i in range(2):
    encoder.append(robot.getDevice(encoderNames[i]))
    encoder[i].enable(TIMESTEP)

oldEncoderValues = []

# initz motors    
leftMotor = robot.getDevice('left wheel motor')
rightMotor = robot.getDevice('right wheel motor')
leftMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
rightMotor.setPosition(float('inf'))
leftMotor.setVelocity(0.0)
rightMotor.setVelocity(0.0)

# Robot Localization functions

def get_wheels_speed(encoderValues, oldEncoderValues, delta_t):
    """Computes speed of the wheels based on encoder readings"""
    #Encoder values indicate the angular position of the wheel in radians
    wl = (encoderValues[0] - oldEncoderValues[0])/delta_t
    wr = (encoderValues[1] - oldEncoderValues[1])/delta_t

    return wl, wr


def get_robot_speeds(wl, wr, r, d):
    """Computes robot linear and angular speeds"""
    u = r/2.0 * (wr + wl)
    w = r/d * (wr - wl)

    return u, w


def get_robot_pose(u, w, x_old, y_old, phi_old, delta_t):
    """Updates robot pose based on heading and linear and angular speeds"""
    delta_phi = w * delta_t
    phi = phi_old + delta_phi
    phi_avg = (phi_old + phi)/2   
    if phi >= np.pi:
        phi = phi - 2*np.pi
    elif phi < -np.pi:
        phi = phi + 2*np.pi
    
    delta_x = u * np.cos(phi_avg) * delta_t
    delta_y = u * np.sin(phi_avg) * delta_t
    x = x_old + delta_x
    y = y_old + delta_y

    return x, y, phi


#------------ Main Loop ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:

    # start simulation step
    robot.step(TIMESTEP)

    # define seconds since start simulation, every step is 0.032 seconds
    totalS = round(totalS + 0.032, 4)
    print(totalS)

    # Read the line sensors:
    gsValues = []
    for i in range(3):
        gsValues.append(gs[i].getValue())

    # Process line sensor data here.
    line_right = round(gsValues[0])
    line_center = round(gsValues[1])
    line_left = round(gsValues[2])
# Data gathering -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    # Read the encoders
    encoderValues = []
    for i in range(2):
        encoderValues.append(encoder[i].getValue())    # [rad]
        
    # Update old encoder values if not done before
    if len(oldEncoderValues) < 2:
        for i in range(2):
            oldEncoderValues.append(encoder[i].getValue())   

#-- Localization -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Compute speed of the wheels
    [wl, wr] = get_wheels_speed(encoderValues, oldEncoderValues, delta_t)
    
    # Compute robot linear and angular speeds
    [u, w] = get_robot_speeds(wl, wr, R, D)
    
    # Compute new robot pose
    [x, y, phi] = get_robot_pose(u, w, x, y, phi, delta_t)

    # update old encoder values for the next cycle
    oldEncoderValues = encoderValues

    print(f'Sim time: {totalS}  Pose: x={x:.2f} m, y={y:.2f} m, phi={phi:.4f} rad.')


#-- Line Following -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # fullspeed ahead
        fullspeed = 0
        if line_left < 500 and line_right < 500:
            leftMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED)
            rightMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED)
            fullspeed = 1
            print('fullspeed')
        # turn Right
        right = 0
        if line_right > 500 and line_left < 500:
            leftMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED)
            rightMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED/2)
            right = 1
            print('right')
        # turn Left
        left = 0
        if line_right < 500 and line_left > 500:
            leftMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED/2)
            rightMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED)
            left = 1
            print('left')
        # if there is no line turn right (most probable as it is a right turning oval)
        if fullspeed == 0 and right == 0 and left == 0: 
            leftMotor.setVelocity(MAX_SPEED)
            rightMotor.setVelocity(2)
            print('houston, we have a problem')
```

I tried to add a gps on the turret slot, but this only resulted in more head ache as i couldn't understand the python documentation and the video i found was outdated according to the IDE. If you have any suggestions on how to improve i would like to hear them. I already fixed the global and local variables in the function in my own snippet, but i tried to keep this snippet as close to the original as possible.

The problem only happens when the robot leaves the line, but i also don't know why that is.